# Rhino features beyond the ECMA standard?

Tags: javascript, rhino, ecma262

I'm starting with JavaScript and the Rhino engine. I know the ECMAScript 262 specification. I need to know what features, e.g. functions/objects/etc are defined by the Rhino JavaScript engine beyond the ECMA standard. Most examples just feature `print`, `Packages` and `import*` but I wasn't able to find an exhaustive list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See predefined properties here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell#Predefined_Properties

This is generally the best page about Rhino and it's JS features: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Rhino_Shell

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an exhaustive list but I have a compat table of non-standard ES features. Take a look at Rhino column — http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/non-standard/.

Note how Rhino's feature set is pretty close to that of SpiderMonkey (latest JS engine in Firefox). There are differences though. For example, Rhino doesn't have **"caller" property** on functions, unlike SpiderMonkey. Rhino supports **e4x** but not **expression closures**. It looks more or less like a subset of SpiderMonkey, although there might be non-standard features that I'm not aware of (in which case I'd love to add them to the table).